# Getting different time for same timestamp on different machines

Tags: java

I am getting different result of below java program on different machines. Both machines are in same time zone and has same time. Anyone know why I am getting two different results for same timestamp on different machines. I am using java 1.8.60 version

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TestClass {

    private static final String DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        private static final String TIME_FORMAT_HH_MM_SS = "HH:mm:ss";
        private static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD + " " + TIME_FORMAT_HH_MM_SS;

        public static void main(final String[] agrs) {
                final long a = 1468634490000L;
            final Timestamp t = new Timestamp(a);
        System.out.println(“time " + convertDateTimeToString(t.toLocalDateTime()));
        }


        public static String convertDateTimeToString(final LocalDateTime date) {
                if (date == null) {
                        return null;
                }
                final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
                return formatter.format(date);
        }
}
```

Machine1 output -> time 2016-07-15 22:01:30

Machine2 output -> time 2016-07-15 02:01:30

Comment: The 2 machines probably have different default time zones... If you include the time zone in your formatter it should become clear.

Comment: You are right one was on UTC and other one was using EST. Thanks :)